# One signal works yesterday but failed / Invalid today

Tags: notifications, onesignal

My collegue tried to set up a one signal app few weeks ago and it works at the beginning but soon it stopped to.

Yesterday, i tried to start a new app on the one signal backoffice : after setting up everything all my 3 browsers worked (Safari / Chrome / Firefox) when i tried to send a notification from the one signal back office.

Today, i take my job, no code where changed during the night and all my notifications fail or are invalids.

Do you know why it works yesterday but not today without any change ? Some spam protection maybe or anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved, my collegue sended a bad params in curl..

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of work : Cleaned my Chrome websites cache because the UserID I got from onesignal was different than the one registered on the back office of onesignal.

Now I have all my 3 id's good (Safaire / Chrome / Firefox) and if I unsub one, it marked as unsub, if I resub it, it is correctly resub but 3 differents answer from onesignal service when i send a message :

-Safari : Ok and receive the push

-Firefox : NOK --> Unreachable state (but id is good and user subscribe)

-Chrome : NOK --> Now user ID is good, subscribe but Invalid state